# Android SQLiteDatabase update multiple rows using where clause with IN or OR

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following code which I was using to update a single row in my database:

```
public int updateSentFieldForIncomingMessage(IncomingMessage incomingMessage)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int numberOfRowsAffected;

    try
    {
        db = super.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    }

    try
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MESSAGE_SENT, true);

        numberOfRowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_INCOMING_MESSAGES, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(incomingMessage.getId())});
    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }

    return numberOfRowsAffected;
}
```

This works fine but now I'd like to refactor the method so that instead of a single IncomingMessage parameter, it accepts a list of IncomingMessage.  But when I get to this statement:

```
db.update(TABLE_INCOMING_MESSAGES, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(incomingMessage.getId())});
```

I'm not sure how to modify it so that I can specify multiple rows (via KEY_ID) in my WHERE clause.  What I'd like to do is say something like `KEY_ID IN ( <multiple row IDs here> )`.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that possible?

it is, but you will need a number of `?` equals to the length of `String[]`. You can use a String builder to create such `whereClause`.

E.g.

```
db.update(TABLE_INCOMING_MESSAGES, values, KEY_ID + " IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?)", new String[]{String.valueOf(incomingMessage.getId()),  "id1", "id2", "id3"});
```

Comment: So if my list had 5 values in it, you mean something like KEY_ID + " = ? OR ? OR ? OR ? OR ?", is that correct?

Comment: KEY_ID IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?), new String[] {"id0", "id1", "id2", "id3"}

Comment: Ahh, ok.  I've got it now.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

In case you have unknown number of arguments, you can also use:

```
String args = TextUtils.join(", ", arrayOfIds);

db.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s = true WHERE %s IN (%s);", 
    TABLE_INCOMING_MESSAGES, KEY_MESSAGE_SENT, KEY_ID, args));
```